# Extracting Specific Text from a log file using PowerShell returning only the last occurrence of the text criteria and skip previous entries

Tags: powershell

I am trying to clean up disk space for a large deployment.
I have a script that does some basic clean up including logging .
currently I am manually determinding what pcs have files that can be cleaned up like PST files moved to online archive and duplicate OST files that were created from an
office migration.

My goal is to  report on the PST files and OST files for the lastest dates in the logs  so i can create tickets for the help desk to move the PST files to the cloud and remove duplicate ost files.
The logs contain an entry to identify the start and end of the section of the log file to search.

Thus I want to identify the following from the log.

- PC name ( I think I can do this with Regex )
- PST files ( I have found the code here that lets me find this section of the log but gets the first occurence)
- OST files ( I can duplicate for OST files with a little tweaking)

What I cannot figure out is how to get the PST text lines and OST text lines from the last time the script ran
For example this script returns the correct text but only from both the 6/7/2023
what I want is the lines from 10/16/2023 entries.

Some logs have data for several runs and I only want the last run data.

I want only the 10/16/2023 part of the log in this example.

What I have so far?
I found a script on this site that got me started but it only returns the first occurence of lines I am looking for.
When it finds the ending text it breaks and that is the end of the search.

what I would appreciate help with is adjusting this so that it finds data beteen $start and $finish but only the data from the last run time.

Here is the code I have so far that I found on this site

```
**# define how many lines before matching `$start`**
$offset = 0
**# expect to find this line in the log**
$start = @(    
'Checking for OST files to Log - THEY WILL NOT BE REMOVED'
)
**# this one signals to break the loop**
$finish = 'End checking for OST files'
**# read the file conten**t

$content = Get-Content "C:\temp\Processlinesinafile\mypcname_Diskspace.log"
$startCapture = $false
$extractedLines = for($i = 0; $i -lt $content.Length; $i++) {
    # if this line matches the index 0 of the `$start` array and
    # the next line matches the index 1
    if($content[$i] -like "*$($start[0])*" ) {
        # then, set this boolean to signal start capturing the following lines
        $startCapture = $true
        # output from this line minus the offset (2 lines above in this case)
        # up to this line and next line
        $content[($i - $offset)..($i + 2)]
        # increment `$i` so we don't check the next line (already did here!)
        $i++
        # and continue with the next loop iteration,
        # we don't want below conditions to be evaluated in this case
        continue
    }
    # if this line matches the string singaling to stop capture
    if($content[$i] -like "*$finish*") {
        # break the loop
        break
    }
    # if the first condition was true then
    if($startCapture) {
        # output this line as-is
        $content[$i]
    }
}
$extractedLines
```

Results - this result is close but I want the data from the October entries.

$extractedLines
6/7/2023 9:38 AM --  Checking for OST files to Log - THEY WILL NOT BE REMOVED
6/7/2023 9:38 AM --  Found OST file - C:\Users\GUQ5\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook\suzanne.wensky@cms.hhs.gov - O365CMSMigration.ost File
size - 7,730.57MB, last updated 06/07/2023 09:37:22
6/7/2023 9:38 AM --  Found OST file - C:\Users\GUQ5\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook\suzanne.wensky@cms.hhs.gov.ost File size - 6,712.57MB,
last updated 06/07/2023 09:03:59
6/7/2023 9:38 AM --  Found OST file - C:\Users\GUQ5\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook\suzanne.wensky@cms.hhs.gov.ost File size - 6,712.57MB,
last updated 06/07/2023 09:03:59

Here is the original log file.

6/7/2023 9:38 AM --
6/7/2023 9:38 AM --  ---------------------
6/7/2023 9:38 AM --  Starting Disk Space Check
6/7/2023 9:38 AM --  Free disk space is 13.08GB
6/7/2023 9:38 AM --  Removing
6/7/2023 9:38 AM --   -- C:\Users*\AppData\Local\Temp*
6/7/2023 9:38 AM --   -- C:\Users*\AppData\Local\CrashDumps*
6/7/2023 9:38 AM --   -- C:\Users*\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\WER*
6/7/2023 9:38 AM --   removing misc windows temp files and recycleBin
6/7/2023 9:38 AM --   removing Aspen dump files
6/7/2023 9:38 AM --  Checking for PST files to Log - THEY WILL NOT BE REMOVED
6/7/2023 9:38 AM --  Found PST file - C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook\2009 (1).pst File size - 33.92MB, last updated 06/07/2023 09:31:54
6/7/2023 9:38 AM --  Found PST file - C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook\2010.pst File size - 176.33MB, last updated 06/07/2023 09:31:57
6/7/2023 9:38 AM --  End checking for PST files
6/7/2023 9:38 AM --  Checking for OST files to Log - THEY WILL NOT BE REMOVED
6/7/2023 9:38 AM --  Found OST file - C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook\email@company.com1.ost File size - 7,730.57MB, last updated 06/07/2023 09:37:22
6/7/2023 9:38 AM --  Found OST file - C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook\email@company.com.ost File size - 6,712.57MB, last updated 06/07/2023 09:03:59
6/7/2023 9:38 AM --  End checking for OST files
6/7/2023 9:38 AM --  Free disk space is 34.54GB
6/7/2023 9:38 AM --  Copying Log to \share\Dump\Diskchecklogs\mypcname_Diskspace.log
6/7/2023 9:38 AM --  End Script
10/16/2023 9:34 AM --
10/16/2023 9:34 AM --  ---------------------
10/16/2023 9:34 AM --  Starting Disk Space Check
10/16/2023 9:34 AM --  Free disk space is 19.89GB
10/16/2023 9:34 AM --  Removing
10/16/2023 9:34 AM --   -- C:\Users*\AppData\Local\Temp*
10/16/2023 9:34 AM --   -- C:\Users*\AppData\Local\CrashDumps*
10/16/2023 9:34 AM --   -- C:\Users*\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\WER*
10/16/2023 9:34 AM --   removing misc windows temp files and recycleBin
10/16/2023 9:34 AM --   removing pun dump files
10/16/2023 9:34 AM --  Checking for PST files to Log - THEY WILL NOT BE REMOVED
10/16/2023 9:34 AM --  Found PST file - C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook\2009 (1).pst File size - 33.92MB, last updated 10/16/2023 09:24:41
10/16/2023 9:34 AM --  Found PST file - C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook\2010.pst File size - 176.33MB, last updated 10/16/2023 09:24:54
10/16/2023 9:34 AM --  Found PST file - C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook\2011.pst File size - 44.58MB, last updated 10/16/2023 09:23:46
10/16/2023 9:34 AM --  Found PST file - C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook\archive.pst File size - 32,283.61MB, last updated 10/16/2023 09:24:17
10/16/2023 9:34 AM --  Found PST file - C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook\Medical homes.pst File size - 0.26MB, last updated 10/16/2023 09:24:54
10/16/2023 9:34 AM --  End checking for PST files
10/16/2023 9:34 AM --  Checking for OST files to Log - THEY WILL NOT BE REMOVED
10/16/2023 9:34 AM --  Found OST file - C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook\email@company.com- O365CMSMigration.ost File size - 8,748.57MB, last updated 10/16/2023 09:33:25
10/16/2023 9:34 AM --  Found OST file - C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook\email@company.com.ost File size - 6,712.57MB, last updated 10/12/2023 09:11:24
10/16/2023 9:34 AM --  End checking for OST files
10/16/2023 9:34 AM --  Free disk space is 35.05GB
10/16/2023 9:34 AM --  Copying Log to \share\mypcname_Diskspace.log